# ERROR: Response is too large | Chainlink Functions

Tags: javascript, chainlink

I am trying to perform a Chainlink Functions request from my smart contract deployed on Polygon Mumbai Testnet.
This is my deployed Contract => [here](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xc26Cf9e181aa2325BE42aE620F3090B87db26627#readContract)

To obtain the Function source Code, call the `zixinToSourceCode` with param value 4.

My Chainlink functions call occurs when I call the `claimZixin` function.

If you observe my event logs, you can see the [latest](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x767762a192a006dfb7847f15b9b1ba11b224ff26241ceff6443593ac872a1c98)event `ErrorOccured` emitted. By decoding the error, I get the error response
**Response is too large**

My functions-simulate work perfectly and return the expected results.

I have shortened the length of every string in the source code with my return value for zixinId 4 is Functions.encodeString("hi")

Please help me out here

Answer (score 0):

Hello [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19430021/gabriel-antony)

I checked your last [claimZixin](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x76a2e3812256a683024e37e73d447615997b005404155d4ba40ae91f9e224ec5)
And I noticed that the gas limit was 100000

Did you try to increase the gas limit?
I suggest you to increase to 300000

Comment: Hey  [Solange Guerios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13622241/solange-gueiros)

I tried increasing the gas Limit. It still did not work. 
I am getting the same error response too large.

I even tried just making 1 API call to reduce complexity.
Still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Chainlink oracle (node operator) here.

Unfortunately the maximum gas limit allowed by Chainlink Functions is `300,000`.

If you need to consume more than this, you'll need to send a Direct Request to a single Chainlink oracle. Direct Requests - also sometimes referred to as Any API requests - have a default gas limit of `500,000`, and can be increased indefinitely by the oracle.

To send a Direct Request from your smart contract, you'll first need to find a Chainlink oracle, who will provide you with the necessary contract code, job id, oracle address, etc. You can do this by either:

1. Posting your requirement to the **#operator-requests** channel of the Chainlink Official Discord server, and waiting for a response from one of the community operators who reside in that channel.
2. Using the website of a known / reputable Chainlink oracle to build your request (we at LinkWell Nodes post all of our oracle addresses, job ids, and contract code samples on our website to get you started, and there are others who do this as well).

Please note that when using the Direct Request model, as you are sending your request to a single Chainlink oracle, it's important to choose one that you trust - ideally one with many years in the industry, and well-versed in redundant, scalable, and distributed infrastructure. The team should have a clear SLA on their website and be able to walk you through and questions you may have.

Best of luck to you!